# fillna : how to pad values over the next x days

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns and indexed by dates. I would like to pad missing values but only for the next x days. It means that a missing value will not be padded if its difference in index is more than x days with the previous non missing value in this column.

I did something with a loop but it is not very efficient. Is there a better and more elegant way of doing it ?

I precise that the dates in my index are not equally spaced so the limit argument will not work.

Comment: Can you provide part of your dataframe that we can solve your problem easier?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `limit` argument of [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', limit=3)  # ffill is equivalent to pad
```

*The same argument is available for the `ffill`, `bfill` convenience functions.*

> `limit : int`, default `None`
>             Maximum size gap to forward or backward fill

If you're dates aren't evenly spaced, you can [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) (by day) first:

```
df.resample('D')
```

*See also the [missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html) section of the docs.*

Comment: it does not work for my case. The dates in my index are not equally spaced

Comment: I already looked into the missing data section in the docs but I see nothing that fits my need

Comment: or reindex to equally spaced dates first?

Comment: Thanks Andy. If I have datetime instead of dates and I do not want to resample as I want to keep my original index, is there a way ?

Comment: limit is based on relative positions (locations) rather than actual index values - this is a feature

Comment: My datetime index is actually up to the second in accuracy. May be I can resample, then pad with limit and then extract only the values I want according to my original index ? Regarding the extraction what is the fastest way to do it ?

Comment: The ideal solution would be to have the option to have a limit based on actual index values but apparently it is not available

Comment: @Jeff I thought there *was* some (non-hacky) way to do this (which I'd used), can't recall it atm.. will consult [the book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do).

Comment: @user2307205 if you would put up a test case this would be easier to help you

Comment: @Andy,Jeff You spotted exactly the problem. I just need a way to solve it now

Comment: It's not in the book, will think about this later (sure I have done it before...), it may be a good feature request?

Comment: I think it could be an awesome feature

Comment: For now Andy, I think I will resample to the second and then use limit. How can I easily extract the values corresponding to my original index from my resampled dataframe ?

Comment: @user2307205 Maybe have a column of originals=True and *don't* ffill that column after the resample.

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates what I meant

```
In [20]: df = DataFrame(randn(10,2),columns=list('AB'),index=date_range('20130101',periods=3)+date_range('20130110',periods=3)+date_range('20130120',periods=4))

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
                   A         B
2013-01-01 -0.176354  1.033962
2013-01-02  0.666911 -0.018723
2013-01-03  0.300097  1.552866
2013-01-10  0.581816 -1.188106
2013-01-11 -0.394817 -1.018765
2013-01-12  1.000461 -1.211131
2013-01-20  0.097940  1.225805
2013-01-21 -2.205975 -0.455641
2013-01-22  0.508865 -0.403321
2013-01-23 -0.726969  0.448002

In [22]: df.reindex(index=date_range('20130101','20130125')).fillna(limit=2,method='pad')
Out[22]: 
                   A         B
2013-01-01 -0.176354  1.033962
2013-01-02  0.666911 -0.018723
2013-01-03  0.300097  1.552866
2013-01-04  0.300097  1.552866
2013-01-05  0.300097  1.552866
2013-01-06       NaN       NaN
2013-01-07       NaN       NaN
2013-01-08       NaN       NaN
2013-01-09       NaN       NaN
2013-01-10  0.581816 -1.188106
2013-01-11 -0.394817 -1.018765
2013-01-12  1.000461 -1.211131
2013-01-13  1.000461 -1.211131
2013-01-14  1.000461 -1.211131
2013-01-15       NaN       NaN
2013-01-16       NaN       NaN
2013-01-17       NaN       NaN
2013-01-18       NaN       NaN
2013-01-19       NaN       NaN
2013-01-20  0.097940  1.225805
2013-01-21 -2.205975 -0.455641
2013-01-22  0.508865 -0.403321
2013-01-23 -0.726969  0.448002
2013-01-24 -0.726969  0.448002
2013-01-25 -0.726969  0.448002
```

Comment: This is what I want Jeff except that you have some missing values in the column B and not in the column A

Comment: How do you combine this with a `value` fill? i.e. df.B.fillna(value=df.A, limit=2, method='pad'), where `B` is empty where `A` is not. Maybe this is worth a whole new question...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just thought about the solution. It would take 3 lines of code :

1/ resample the dataframe to the second
2/ fillna with limit
3/ reindex my new dataframe with the index of the original one

In terms of speed I do not how it will look but should be fine I think as most of the pandas functions are implemented in cython

Comment: Resample for every second could be a rather a large overhead though. :s

Comment: yes I know but do you think of a better solution ? Otherwise I would just implement the method I need in cython

Comment: Andy I am currently looking at the code in pandas. I think it should not be too difficult to modify the code to accept this option. Do you know in which file the function fillna is implemented ?

Comment: It's in pandas/core/frame.py and pandas/core/series.py (plus a few more), [pull requests](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pulls) greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I will definitely do. I will create a patch and create a push request so you can review it

Comment: Did anything happen with changing limit to allowing something like a timedelta limit rather than number of rows?  I implemented a hacky way to do this that might work better for datasets with a much greater time gap between samples than the time accuracy of the samples (e.g. samples up to days apart with a timestamp to the nearest second).

Answer (score 0):

In the vein of Onyxx's answer, I solved the same issue as follows:

1. Add a column to the dataframe for the index date, set to nan where data to be filled is nan.
2. Fill index date column and data
3. Set nans where backfilled index date is too old.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by implementing a cython function that would do the job for a Series. I just call this function on each column of my dataframe to do this.